# How can I add new users to mongoDB database directly from a excel sheet in Node js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I want a feature for admins that he can add new users or register new users to the mongoDB database directly from an excel sheet instead of manually filling all details. How can it be implemented in nodejs?

Comment: You should take a look at the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)

Comment: Try parsing the file using libraries like [`xlsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) and post doing that use the [`insertMany api`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) to batch add multiple documents

Answer (score 0):

You can use **convert-excel-to-json** npm package.